CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand is not working on iOS (MAUI .NET 8.0)?
I have a problem with a RelayCommand not working (CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand) in iOS in a .NET 8.0 MAUI app. This RelayCommand is somehow not triggering in iOS while it works on Windows and Android. This takes place in an MVVM .NET 8.0 MAUI app that targets Android, Windows, and iOS.
For the opening screen I use a ViewModel in which in the constructor these RelayCommands are defined:
ChangeSettingsCommand = new CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand<Models.ModelLogin>(OnChangeSettings, CanChangeSettings);
ChangeSettingsCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();

In the ViewModel the OnChangeSettings and CanChangeSettings methods are as followed:
 public CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand<Models.ModelLogin> ChangeSettingsCommand { get; set; }

 public bool CanChangeSettings(object paramater)
 {
     return true;
 }

 #endregion

 internal void OnChangeSettings(object parameter)
 {
     ChangeSettingsEvent?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
 }

The OnChangeSettings method invokes an event defined in the view (...xaml.cs):
moLogin.ChangeSettingsEvent += MoLogin_ChangeSettingsEvent;





  private async void MoLogin_ChangeSettingsEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      await Utils.PushAsyncWithoutDuplicate(new InitialSettingsNew(true));
  }

In the view the command is 'set' to a button like this (moLogin is the ViewModel):
  lst.Add(new Controls.Phone.PBImageButton()
  {
      Command = moLogin.ChangeSettingsCommand, 
      //BindingContext = moLogin,
      //ButtonImageFile = Utils.OnPlatform<string>("Toolbar/settingswhite.png", "settingswhite.png", "Images/White/settings.png"),
      Source = "w_settings.png",
      //Behaviors.Add(behavior),
      BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent,
      ButtonBorderColor = Colors.Transparent,
      VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
      HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
      HeightRequest = 40,
      WidthRequest = 40

  });

In the constuctor of the PBImageButton (a custom control which derives from an ImageButton ) the ICommand is set as followed:
public PBImageButton()
{
    this.CornerRadius = 0;
    this.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
    this.Padding = new Thickness(5);

    SetupGrid();

    TapGestureRecognizer t = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    
    this.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
    {
        Command = ExecuteCommand
    });

    
}

The ExecuteCommand (ICommand) property of the PBImageButton is as followed:
private ICommand ExecuteCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            if (this.IsEnabled)
            {
                await this.ScaleTo(0.8, 50, Easing.Linear);
                await Task.Delay(100);
                await this.ScaleTo(1, 50, Easing.Linear);

                PBImageButtonClicked?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                this.Command?.Execute(CommandParameter);
            }
        }
        );
    }
}

If I set a breakpoint in the method: OnChangeSettings in the ViewModel this breakpoint is triggered in Windows and Android but on iOS this method is not triggered.
So somehow the PBImageButton command (which is a System.Windows.Input.ICommand property) is not working on iOS.
I have already tried the following things to solve it:
1.
Looks like this might be the cause:
https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/2065

When the name of a RelayCommand is prefixed with "On", the command
will never be triggered.

Removing 'On..' didn't solve it.
2.
Use a RelayCommand attribute (instead of defining the RelayCommand in C# itself):
[RelayCommand]
internal void ChangeSettings(object parameter)
{
    ChangeSettingsEvent?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
}

This didn't solve it either.
3.
Using :
https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnetMAUI/comments/16wvb72/communitytoolkitmvvm_relaycommand_not_working/?rdt=51962
        ChangeSettings = new CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand<Models.ModelLogin>(OnChangeSettings, CanChangeSettings);
        ChangeSettings.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();

Instead of:
        ChangeSettingsCommand = new CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand<Models.ModelLogin>(OnChangeSettings, CanChangeSettings);
        ChangeSettingsCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();

This didn't solve it.
4.
When I directly use a PBImageButton with a command binding in the view.......:
 <ucp:PBImageButton Grid.Row="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Command="{Binding ChangeSettingsCommand}" Margin="0" Padding="0" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" ButtonText="test" Background="Red"/>

It does work on Windows and Android but not on iOS. This is not a solution either.
5.
Using 'public' instead of 'internal' in the method below:
 public void OnChangeSettings(object parameter)
 {
     ChangeSettingsEvent?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
 }

This didn't solve it either though.

I think it might be a problem related to .NET 8.0, because I used the same code in another MAUI app that works with MAUI .NET 7.0 and here this problem didn't occur.
Does anybody know if there are known issues with iOS and .NET 8.0 concerning the RelayCommand (CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand)?
Does anybody know what goes wrong here? Maybe it is something obvious I overlook.

First of all, I recommend using the RelayCommand attribute. Then in code behind, test it by directly calling the command. For example, ViewModel.ChangeSettingsCommand.Execute(null);.

So the View where command is supposed to fire is dynamically added? not statically defined?

Thank you. If I use a RelayCommand attribute and then call the command like this: ViewModel.ChangeSettingsCommand.Execute(null) in the constructor of the view the command is triggered on iOS! But it doesn't work when I click the PBImageButton. Somehow the ICommand (System.Windows.Input.ICommand) is not working in this control? I don't exactly know yet what goes wrong here. But it seems that the problem is in this (custom) control.

By the way; if I don't use the RelayCommand attribute and define the RelayCommands in the constructor of the ViewModel (see the opening post) the command is also triggered when calling: ViewModel.ChangeSettingsCommand.Execute(null); in the view. So it doesn't have anything to do with the RelayCommand attribute.

Bhavanesh N; the control (PBImageButton) where the command is supposed to be fired is indeed dynamically added to a control in the view.

By the way: the control uses a so called: TapGestureRecognizer for the command (ICommand) :   TapGestureRecognizer t = new TapGestureRecognizer();
this.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
{
Command = ExecuteCommand
}); . It might have something to do with this TapGestureRecognizer.

I think this might be the issue that is causing this problem: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/25237

Since you can programmatically call the command, the command's source generator is working. I think the link you provided is the issue here. You should be able to confirm this by binding the command to another control, a Button for instance.

Thank you. The PBImageButton derived from an ImageButton. I now let it derive from an Image (control) and now the command works! Somehow using the TapGestureRecognizer in an ImageButton (when using MAUI .NET 8.0) is causing this problem.

This problem is solved now.
The PBImageButton I used was deriving from a Microsoft.MAUI.Controls.ImageButton:
   public class PBImageButton : ImageButton
   {

When I let it derive from a Microsoft.MAUI.Controls.Image it works fine:
 public class PBImageButton : Image
 {

The reason why it doesn't work with the ImageButton is probably because of using the TapGestureRecognizer in combination with .NET MAUI 8.0. This seems to be a known issue:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/25237
The Image control has no padding property and no border color property but it is a good solution to use the Image control instead of the ImageButton control.
